# just another mod_rewrite question

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

from the url

```
xxx.yyy.site.com
```

just need to redirect to

```
xxx.site.com
```

Thanks for the help, sorry I have no regex/rewrite foo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This rule will redirect (301 Permanent Redirect) all incoming requests to `xxx.yyy.site.com` domain to `http://xxx.site.com/` preserving the URL path (e.g. `http://xxx.yyy.site.com/kitten?say=meow` will be redirected to `http://xxx.site.com/kitten?say=meow`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =xxx.yyy.site.com
RewriteRule .* http://xxx.site.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This rule does not take into consideration HTTPS -- it will always redirect to HTTP. If it needs to preserve protocol as well (`http -> http` and `https -> https`), then you will need to have 2 rules (one for each protocol) and one extra rewrite condition for each rule (which will take protocol into consideration).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Much appreciated, was having a bit of an issue at work.